# Attempt to de-reference a null object on CPQ UI Vlocity

Tags: community, cpq, vlocity

I get this error in my CPQ UI Vlocity(Attempt to de-reference a null object)  in all environments  after a deployment of my products .

The issue is occured only when i change the value of the picklist of attribute (Tarification) to Sécurisé ,when i choose Standard ,the error is not displayaed again .

When i checked the json of my quotelineitem ,the value of the attribute is updated correctly with Sécurisé value ,but why i have this error message and prices are not appeared again

How can i fix this problem ,i run all cmt jobs and i have executed this code to fix json attributes but the error message remains

```
List<Id> productIds = new List<Id>();

for (Product2 prod : [ Select Id from Product2 where vlocity_cmt__ObjectTypeId__c != null ]) {
    productIds.add(prod.Id);
}

Database.executeBatch(new vlocity_cmt.EPCProductAttribJSONBatchJob(productIds), 1);
```

Thanks a lot for your help .

[image]

[image]

Comment: Null pointer exceptions should be easy to track if coming from your codebase and not inside managed package. Have you tried adding debug logs and check this?

Comment: this error appears in the CPQ  UI of vlocity,not in y code ,in the debug ,i can't see anything

Comment: Did you get the resolution to this issue? If yes, could you please share the solution here. I'm in the same situation.
Thanks